# Deploying to Rackspce Cloud using Cloud Foundry and VMC

Tags: rackspace-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm just wondering how do I use Cloud Foundry VMC to deploy my application to different cloud providers?

In particular Rackspace Cloud.

I know there are services that use cloud foundry like AppFog, but they don't really support RS Cloud at the moment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cloud Foundry, you can either deploy to the official Cloud Foundry servers (which requires an account), or you can use the VMWare virtual machine image ("Micro Cloud Foundry") they provide to launch your own.  Basically, Micro Cloud Foundry is just a bunch of Ruby scripts and what have you that means it can run on a variety of operating systems--which doesn't depend on the provider.

Comment: But how can I set Micro Cloud Foundry instance to scale horizontally?  sorry if my question sounds absurd, I'm just starting to get the concept behind this.

Comment: That is something that is not relevant to MCF, actually.  If you want the hardware to scale, you'll need monitoring to act on high resource usage and deploy new machines.  Things like Rackspace Cloud, Amazon EC2, etc., provide the hardware, not the infrastructure for autoscaling.